# Recursive pip update

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install a package using `pip`.  Pip informed me that it was out of date and I should update it.  When I tried to update `pip` it told me that I was already up to date and that a new version of `pip` is available and I should use the command I just used to update it.

```
➜  ~  pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What is wrong?  How do I update pip and break the cycle?

System info:

```
➜  ~  which python
/opt/local/bin/python
➜  ~  python --version
Python 3.4.3
➜  ~  which pip
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip
➜  ~  pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```